# Very jerky scrolling NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder

I have an NSScrollView which contains an NSTableView, this has 3 columns, 1 of which has a custom view in it via TableCellView.

To load images into this cell via background processes, i have subclassed the cell using the below code. However the scrolling is really jerky, i am wondering if there is any way to optimise this, the images are not very large, 48x48, and are being displayed at 51x51.

I suspect the fact that a fetch request is being used for each row is probably not very efficient, and i need to find a way to set an NSArray each time the view is changed that is current, and use that instead. But i was wanting to get this as efficient as possible first.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

// Get a new ViewCell
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

//Identify the correct column
if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"userLogo"] )
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
    if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }


    //Setup the Request
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

    //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;

    //Create an array from the returned objects
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    Tweet *selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    cellView.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("getAsynchronIconsGDQueue", NULL),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedTweet.avatarUrl];
                       NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       cellView.imageView.image = image;
                   });
    [cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
    return cellView;
     }

    [cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
    return cellView;
}
```

Thanks

Gareth

**EDIT 1**

Ok have tried implementing AFImageRequest, and performance is worst, and also i seem to get getting multiple copies of the same image/the wrong image in various rows.

Here is the code i am using.

```
@synthesize profileImage = _profileImage;

+ (NSOperationQueue *)sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue {
static NSOperationQueue *_sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [_sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:8];
});

return _sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue;
}

//Load the image into the table

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

// Get a new ViewCell
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

//Identify the correct column
if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"userLogo"] )
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
    if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }


    //Setup the Request
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

    //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;

    //Create an array from the returned objects
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    Tweet *selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedTweet.avatarUrl];

    /*cellView.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("getAsynchronIconsGDQueue", NULL),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedTweet.avatarUrl];
                       NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       cellView.imageView.image = image;
                   });

     */

     _avatarImageRequestOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] success:^(NSImage *image) {
     cellView.imageView.image = self.profileImage;

     _avatarImageRequestOperation = nil;

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUserProfileImageDidLoadNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
     }];

     [_avatarImageRequestOperation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
     return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:cachedResponse.response data:cachedResponse.data userInfo:cachedResponse.userInfo storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
     }];

     [[[self class] sharedProfileImageRequestOperationQueue] addOperation:_avatarImageRequestOperation];

    //cellView.imageView.image = self.profileImage;

    //[cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
    return cellView;

}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at this very carefully (rushed today), but would like to suggest something. What I tend to do in this case is use a background thread to load the first few (say 10 or so) images and add them to the table view cells. Then I use an NSTimer to load a few more every second or so. This allows the pacing to spread itself out more. After the images are loaded I cache them so they are available faster in the future. You might want to consider doing something similar. I also will max out what it can load if there are a lot of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some more troubleshooting i removed the image altogether and the table was still dog slow. So, i have now written a new function that maintains an array of the current selection of objects to save the table drawing function calling it for every row. This has completely fixed the issue and everything is now buttery smooth and lovely.

So it appears that a fetch request is really expensive!

Cheers

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

A few things spring to mind:

1. Currently, you're thrashing the network - there's no caching, and each time a cell is loaded, it will perform networking to retrieve a file it probably already has
2. Have you tried [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the image retrieval? There's a particularly pleasant 'UIImageView+AFNetworking.h' category, that does exactly what you need, really well.
3. Have you tried moving the following off of the main thread?

> NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

```
//Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
} else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
} else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
} else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
[request setPredicate:testForTrue];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}


//Setup the Request
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

//Assign the predicate to the fetch request
NSError *error = nil;

//Create an array from the returned objects
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Tweet *selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: Moving the fetch off to a second thread doesn't seem to make any difference, i have tried implementing AFNetworking, however i am obviously not quite getting it, i used the code above and and i end up with both missing and duplicate images . . . would love to get it working as the demo app that is in the AFNetworking source has the most lovely buttery smooth scrolling!